# Set TaskSubtype=Call by URL Custom Log a Call

Tags: custom-button, tasks, button-overrides, standard, log-a-call

The standard "Log a call" is:

[image]

I have a custom "Log a Call" button on Lead Object, This is de URL:

```
/00T/e?title=Call&who_id={!Lead.Id}&tsk5=Call&tsk4={!TODAY()}&RecordType=0123C000000a3kU&retURL=%2F{!Lead.Id}
```

[image]

but this creates a task of type task, not of type call.

[image]

How can you set the TaskSubtype=Call from the URL, without use followup? I already tried with variations of tsk5, tsk6, tsk7... tsk20 and it doesn't work

Comment: so `tsk5=Call` is the correct URL param. Is it possible you have automation on `Task` that changes `Call` to `Task`? Is `Call` a valid picklist value for `Task.Type`?. Are you sure you are looking at the OOTB field Task.Type on the UX and not some other field with the same label?

Comment: No, this happens in my environment and in a trailhead Playground like in the images, I know that tsk4 = Due Date, tsk6 = Comments, etc... but none of them set the TaskSubtype or the Type field (it should be tsk10=type but although set it, it's still a task you sybtype task and not call)

Comment: Lightning or Classic?

Comment: Classic, this solution only works in Classic

Comment: Have you done this? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000332230

Comment: the url is broken

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000332230&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1

Comment: That link is good data, thank you, it allows me to set type=Call of the task, the only problem is that TaskSubtype is not set automatically, I still could not find the tskNumero= TaskSubtype, otherwise the only option would be to automate the setting of TaskSubtype=Call

Answer (score 1):

Setting fields via URL hacking requires matching the URL param to the field's id (as defined in the HTML)

For Task.TaskSubtype, this can be seen by using your browser's developer tools:

```
<select id="TaskSubtype" name="TaskSubtype" tabindex="12">
    <option value="">--None--</option><option value="task">Task</option>
    <option value="email">Email</option>
    <option value="listEmail">List Email</option>
    <option value="cadence">Cadence</option>
    <option value="call">Call</option>
</select>
```

So, to set Task.TaskSubtype, your URL should look like this:

```
/00T/e?title=Call&who_id={!Lead.Id}&TaskSubtype=call
  &tsk5=Call&tsk4={!TODAY()}
  &RecordType=0123C000000a3kU&retURL=%2F{!Lead.Id}
```

- URL parameter is case sensitive
- URL param value should be the value of the desired `<option>`

I apologize for misreading your question and responding with &tsk5 as that is used for the Task.Type field

Most OOTB fields used in URL hacking (Classic) are the same as the field's API name, but for Task, we have these `tsk`*i* params which no doubt are for some long ago historical reason